# How to use a wildcard or Like in a countif in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard, countif

Let's say in a list of numbers/characters that are supposed to be zip codes, I want to find and coumt the cells that are actually phone numbers.

I know in excel I could use: "???-???-????" To filter it out or: countif(a:a, "???-???-????")

How would I do this using something like:

```
 Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A100"), "???-???-????"
```

Everytime I do the above it always gives me zero.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Suggest you  read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then edit your original question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce your issue was by inserting leading or trailing spaces to correctly formed phone numbers. You could either trim your data programmatically, or use more wildcards in `CountIf`:

```
Range("D1").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A100"), "*???-???-????*")
```